# Reduce method on an array – how does it work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I found this AngularJS code and I don't understand how the sum-function works:

1. What is `reduce` for?
2. How is the parameter toral set or saved?
3. Why is there a '0' at the end?

### JavaScript

```
.factory('Cart', function() {
    var items = [];
    return {
        sum: function() {
            return items.reduce(function(total, article) {
            return total + article.price;
        }, 0);
    }
 });
```

### HTML

```
<table ng-show="cart.getItems().length" class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in cart.getItems() track by $index" class="cart-item">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.price | currency}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{cart.getItems().length}} Artikel</td>
        <td>{{cart.sum() | currency}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Answer : 1 -->
>   Array.prototype.reduce() is applied against an array, and will subsequently iterate through each and every value until and unless it reduces to one single value.
>
> Syntax : arr.reduce(callback,[initialValue])
>
> Answer : 2 --> 
>   Total is the value that is being returned from the previous iteration, and the second argument refers to the current item [value] in the iteration.
>
> Answer : 3 --> 
>   0 is for the initial value, since we are going to do a sum, we need to initialize the value from 0.

Answer (score 1):

### Reduce (part of ES5)

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) has to reduce it to a single value.
>
> **reduce** executes the callback function once for each element present in the array, excluding holes in the array, receiving four arguments: the initial value (or value from the previous callback call), the value of the current element, the current index, and the array over which iteration is occurring.

### Total as argument and 0

Total is accumulator that saves value of previous calculation, `0` is initial value and second argument for `reduce` method as it syntax is:

`arr.reduce(callback,[initialValue]);`

### How it works?

`items.reduce` returns value – calculation of total sum for every items, `sum: return items.reduce` returns calculated value.

**Documentation**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce